# Highcharts heatmap not displaying colors

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I am playing around with Highcharts heatmaps but for some reason the chart is not displaying colors in the cells. What am I missing?

[image]
Here is a link to my playground: https://jsfiddle.net/2f7cdyru/2/

```
function getPointCategoryName(point, dimension) {
  var series = point.series,
    isY = dimension === 'y',
    axis = series[isY ? 'yAxis' : 'xAxis'];
  return axis.categories[point[isY ? 'y' : 'x']];
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    plotBorderWidth: 1
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1),
    max: Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5),
    labels: {
      align: 'center'
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 280
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'x') + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
        this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'y') + '</b>';
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 45],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 60],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 75],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 45],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 60],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 45],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 15],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 30],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 1), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 2), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 3), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 4), 0],
      [Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), Date.UTC(2023, 9, 5), 15],
    ],
    colsize: 24 * 36e5,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }]

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than `colsize` you need to also set `rowsize`. That's because the default value (1) is really small on datetime axes and doesn't create graphic with proper height.

```
  series: [{
    data: [...],
    colsize: 24 * 36e5,
    rowsize: 24 * 36e5,
    ...
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/62Lauetz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.rowsize

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer late, I was distracted by other projects :) thank you for your quick reply!